# Dr. rer. med Title

Tags: phd, graduate-school, thesis, university, titles

The doctorate title "**Dr. rer. med**" is awarded to non-medical postgraduate researchers from University Hospitals.

Is it equivalent to a PhD, or Dr. Eng. etc.?

Is it recognisable in other countries abroad, besides Germany?

Is it acceptable for both academia positions and private sector?

Comment: [This answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/84734/17254) seems to have some of the information you're looking for.